# Flutter type 'List<Future<Widget>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error: 
type 'List>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Here is the code that's triggering the error.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.productId != null) {
      return StreamBuilder(
          stream:
              Document<Product>(path: 'app-data-inventory/${widget.productId}')
                  .streamData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
            if (snap.hasError) {
              print(snap.error);
            }
            if (snap.hasData) {
              Product product = snap.data;

              return Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                backgroundColor: AppAppTheme.white,
                appBar: appBarComponents,
                key: _scaffoldKey,
                body: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                       Builder(
                            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      color: AppAppTheme.primary,
                                      height: 230,
                                      child: _yourWidget(context, product.productStorage['paths']),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    CheckboxListTile(
                                        title: const Text('Terms of services'),
                                        value: _product.termsAgreed != null
                                            ? _product.termsAgreed
                                            : false,
                                        onChanged: (val) {
                                          setState(
                                              () => _product.termsAgreed = val);
                                        }),
                                    SwitchListTile(
                                        title: const Text('Save as draft'),
                                        value: _product.productStatus == 'draft'
                                            ? true
                                            : false,
                                        onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() {
                                              _product.productStatus =
                                                  val ? 'draft' : 'unapproved';
                                            })),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          )

                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return UIErrorsMessages.notFoundComponent(
                  context, 'Product not found!');
            }
          });
    } else {
      return UIErrorsMessages.somethingIsNotRightComponent(
          context, 'Something went wrong. Try again!');
    }
  }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch the data first using `FutureBuilder` and then provide the data to your widgets.

Following code should work for you:

(I didn't have the full code so I have not tested this, in case of any issue please comment)

```
Widget _yourWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return 
          color: AppTheme.primary,
          height: 230,
          child: Wrap(
            children: 
            paths.map<Widget>((url) {
              return FutureBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData){
                  file = snapshot.data;
                  print(file);
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'Delete',
                          style: AppTheme
                              .titleWhite,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(url);
                        },
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 100.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets
                                .all(
                                    10),
                        color:
                            AppTheme
                                .warn,
                        child: ExtendedImage
                            .network(file ==
                                    null
                                ? '/assets/icons/icon-120x120.png'
                                : file),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }else{
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },);
       });
  }

  Future fetchDownloadURL(){
    return await _storage
               .ref()
             .child(url)
             .getDownloadURL();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. But just calling ``future:  fetchDownloadURL()``, won't make sense. Given that it requires an argument(``url``) for it to return the ``downloadURL``. The urls are in an array call paths. So one will need to do some type of loop to get each url before passing the argument to  ``future: fetchDownloadURL(),``. Unless I am getting it all wrong??

Comment: Wrap FutureBuilder around Column Widget and give url in parameter to  fetchDownloadURL() and it should work for you.

Comment: I have something like this: ``Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                         Builder(
                            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      child: _yourWidget(context, paths)``  But I do get the url not defined error on the ``fetchDownloadUrl()``. Probably I am not understanding what you mean.

Comment: Every thing is correct, the thing is if you want to use Future in your widget tree then you need to use FutureBuilder. In your code you are using Future over the Column Widget because you need data there. Now wrap that widget with FutureBuilder and when you receive data pass it to Column till then show loading widgetor some thing like that.

Comment: Thank you. I will add an update to my question code. Hopefully, you'll guide me through better.

Comment: Yes, sure. It will help.

Comment: Is this code not working ?? You won't be getting Flutter type 'List<Future<Widget>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' error in this code. are you still getting the same error ??

Comment: yes sure!. It doesn't work because of the fetchDownloadUrl()... I can't even save the file to reload it because url is undefined. ``Future fetchDownloadURL() async {
    return await _storage
               .ref()
             .child(url)
             .getDownloadURL();
  }``

Comment: That's okay. What I am saying is, in the ``fetchDownloadUrl()``, there is an undefined argument at this point ``.child(url)``. The ``url`` is undefined. ``Undefined name 'url'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.``

Comment: You mean that you don't have url value in fetchDownloadUrl(), I already mention that you should take it in method parameter like fetchDownloadUrl(String url) and that is the only reason I asked you to wrap Coloumn with FutureBuilder. Does this solve the problem.

Comment: Right, but the only way that String url to pass to fetchDownloadUrl() is that some loop on the futureBuilder.  ``Widget _yourWidget(BuildContext context, paths) {
   for(var path in paths){
     return FutureBuilder(
      future: fetchDownloadURL(path), ..}``. Is this what you are supposing I do?

Comment: No, fetchDownloadUrl() is in the map operator and so it is always going to get one url at a time and eventually all the urls. So you don't need to loop over every URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204253/discussion-between-learntoday-and-kalpesh-kundanani).